# Update status (publish) of 60000 nodes

Tags: php, sql, drupal, drupal-6

I have approximately 60.000 nodes in my Drupal installation.

They are all unpublished, and I need to publish all of them. I'm trying to publish them from "Content menu" but I can only select all nodes in a single page.

How can I select *all* nodes in my website ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it with sql.

```
UPDATE node SET status = 1;
```

Comment: this will be the fastest way to do it, if you don't have sql access then Views Bulk Operations below can help automate it, but you'll have to create a view first.

Comment: @omerida: If you can install a module, you can just install devel and run the query through db_query() using the execute php block.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) for that.